# Why does using zip() only write to CSV file when list contains something?

Tags: python, csv, zip

*This is my first time asking a question here and apologize in advance if I haven't formatted the question correctly. I also don't have a lot of experience using python.*

I am writing code which writes two lists to a CSV file. The purpose of the code is for the lists to get written to the file only when they both contain something.

I have been using trial and error but discovered that this is possible when using `ZIP` in python 3:

```
with open('file.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(x,y))
    f.close()
```

Therefore if `x` and `y` both contain something, both lists are written to the CSV file. But if `x` and/or `y` didn't contain something, nothing will happen which is exactly how I want the code to work.

However, what **I'm struggling to understand** is **WHY/HOW using `ZIP` allows this to work.**

Many thanks. Sorry if anything is unclear.

Comment: [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) uses the shortest sequence. If you want to use the longest sequence, use [**`itertools.izip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: @PeterWood 
Sorry, May I ask what you mean exactly by shortest sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) uses the shortest sequence. From the documentation:

> `zip([iterable, ...])`
>   The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

So, if you have an empty sequence you will get nothing:

```
>>> some = [1, 2, 3]
>>> empty = []
>>> zip(some, empty)
[]
```

Use [**`itertools.izip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) if you want to use the longest sequence. It will fill in `None` by default for missing values, or you can specify a new `fillvalue`:

> `itertools.izip_longest(*iterables[, fillvalue])`
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> some = [1, 2, 3]
>>> shorter = ['a', 'b']
>>> list(izip_longest(some, shorter))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, None)]
```

Comment: @BenF97 Edited with example